# What's the meaning of annotations (internal property) in google dev tools watch window?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Would someone please explain what's the meaning of those annotations after the `:` in google dev console?

[image]

For example, when I enter `baz` in console, it returns a triangle with an annotation `Foo` aside. What does this `Foo` mean?

And what's the meaning of `Object` in `__proto__: Object`?

[image]

Another question is when I hang my mouse on the little blue `i` button, it prompts that `Value below was evaluated just now`. What does this mean?

I tried to find some references for those questions but failed. Any resources would be very welcomed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does this Foo mean?

It's the name of the constructor used to create this object.

```
function Foo(){} // constructor function
new Foo()
```

[image]

> And what's the meaning of Object in **proto**: Object?

It's the next prototype up in the prototype chain, the object `baz` inherits from.

Try this slightly more complex example:

```
function Bar(){}
Bar.prototype.someFunction = function(){}
function Foo(){}
Foo.prototype = Object.create(Bar.prototype, {}) // or Foo.prototype = new Bar()
new Foo()
```

The first value in Foo's prototype chain is an instance of the Bar object. The Bar object also has a prototype, but it's just an unnamed object (it doesn't have a constructor function like Foo or Bar).

That object then also has a prototype, which is just the generic [`Object.prototype`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype) that all objects inherit from.

[image]

> Another question is when I hang my mouse on the little blue i button, it prompts that Value below was evaluated just now. What does this mean?

It means the object is shown with the property values it has now, not with the values it had at the time of being logged.

Take this example:

```
var obj = {a: 20}
console.log(obj)
obj.a = 100
```

At first DevTools will print a basic snapshot of the object:

[image]

But when you expand the object DevTools uses the current values of the object rather than using a snapshot.

[image]

Comment: Awesome answer Matt! Thanks for your very detail reply! But would you please tell me where can I find some official references explaining those DevTools Utilities?

Comment: @spacegoing The official docs are [here](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/), but I don't think they have that level of detail on all features.

Comment: Many thanks for your reply! I searched that site before asking questions but found none of them :( Thanks all the same:D